Show that $\int_{(0, 2\pi)} \frac{\cos(2\theta) d\theta}{5+3 \cos(\theta)} = \frac{\pi}{18}$ using residue theory
Let $\theta=e^{iz}$ with $C : |z| <= 1$ it implies $d \theta = \frac{dz}{iz}$
and then we can get
$\cos \theta = \frac{1}{2} (z+\frac{1}{z})$
and $\cos(2\theta) = \frac{1}{2}(z^2+\frac{1}{z^2})$
so i got that
$\int_{(0, 2\pi)} \frac{\cos(2\theta) d\theta}{5+3 \cos(\theta)} = \int_{C)} \frac{\frac{1}{2}(z^2+\frac{1}{z^2})}{5+3(\frac{1}{2} (z+\frac{1}{z}))} \frac{dz}{iz}$
with some manipulation i got that
$f(z)=\frac{i(z^4+1)}{-3z^2(z+3)(z+1/3)}$
$f(z)$ has pole with order 2 at $z_1=0$ and simple pole at $z_2=-1/3$
However, i'm stuck in finding the $Res[f,0]$
here, what i have tried
$Res[f,0] = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{d^2}{dz^2}z^2 (\frac{i(z^4+1)}{-3z^2(z+3)(z+1/3)})$
$ = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{d^2}{dz^2}(\frac{i(z^4+1)}{-3(z+3)(z+1/3)})$
$ = \frac{-i}{3} \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{d^2}{dz^2}(\frac{(z^4+1)}{(z+3)(z+1/3)})$
$ = \frac{-i}{3} \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{d^2}{dz^2}(\frac{(z^4+1)}{z^2+\frac{10}{3}z +1})$
$ = \frac{-i}{3} \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{d}{dz}(\frac{2z^5+10z^4+4z^3-2z-\frac{10}{3}}{(z^2+\frac{10}{3}z +1)^2})$
$ = \frac{-i}{3} \lim_{z \to 0} (\frac{10z^4+30z^3+12z^2-2}{(z^2+\frac{10}{3}z+1)^2}-\frac{2(2z+\frac{10}{3})(2z^5+10z^4+4z^3-2z-\frac{10}{3})}{(z^2+\frac{10}{3}z +1)^3})$
= $\frac{-182i}{27}$
is this right?

$\cos(2\theta)=2\cos\theta\sin\theta$, then $u=\cos\theta$

There's no need of complex numbers. Just the "u" substitution

I have to use the complex number and use the residue theory

@MathStackexchangeIsMarvellous $\cos (2\theta)=\cos^2 \theta -\sin^2 \theta$

@SineoftheTime i never thought I would make a mistake this bad

Too long for a comment.
You have made an error in the evaluation of $\operatorname{Res}(f, 0)$. Instead, $$\operatorname{Res}(f,0) = \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\mathrm d}{dz}(z^2f(z)) = \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\mathrm d}{dz} \left(\frac{i(z^4 + 1)}{-3(z+3)(z+1/3)}\right) = \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{-2i(z^5+15z^4+6z^3-3z-5)}{(z+3)^2 (3z+1)^2} = \frac{10i}9$$
Your error lied in the formula for calculating a residue at a higher order pole, particularly you used the second order derivative of $z^2f(z)$ while you were supposed to use the the first order derivative. Generally for a pole at $c$ of order $k$ of $f(z)$, we have $$\operatorname{Res}(f,c) = \lim_{z\to c}\frac1{(k-1)!} \frac{\mathrm d^{k-1}}{\mathrm dz^{k-1}}((z-c)^k f(z))$$

Thank you so much, i was wondering for a long time which part I was wrong, and it turns out to be the formula.

@Ocean if you are satisfied by any of the answers, you can mark it correct by clicking on the checkmark; it signifies the question has been resolved.

$$\int^{2\pi}_{0}\frac{\cos(2\theta) }{5+3 \cos(\theta)}d\theta = \frac{1}{i}\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{z^4+1}{z^2(3z+1)(z+3)}dz=2\pi(\text{Res(}f(z),0)+\text{Res(}f(z),-\frac{1}{3}))$$
we have :
$$\text{Res(}f(z),0)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d}{dz}\left({\frac{z^4+1}{(3z+1)(z+3)}}\right)=-\frac{10}{9}$$
$$\text{Res(}f(z),-\frac{1}{3})=\lim_{z\to -\frac{1}{3}}\frac{z^4+1}{3z^2(z+3)}=\frac{41}{36}$$
Therfore:
$$\int^{2\pi}_{0}\frac{\cos(2\theta) }{5+3 \cos(\theta)}d\theta=2\pi(\frac{41}{36}-\frac{10}{9})=\frac{\pi}{18}$$

Thank you so much, i was wondering for a long time which part I was wrong, and it turns out to be the formula.
